# Loading phone contacts in ascending order

Tags: android

I am trying to load phone contacts and tried to show the contact names in ascending order.  My code is given below:

```
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = 1", null,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

I got the required output. But a problem is there, names staring with small letter is shown as last one. First the capital letters are sorted, only after that contact names staring with small letters is shown. PLS HELP

OUTPUT IS:

```
Alfin A
Bipin B
Calvin C
Jobin
Shine
anurag U
shine H
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
   ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = 1", 
   null, 
   "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
```

Comment: Thanks sarwar, I used for this query of Cursor and sorted order of contacts with lowercase and uppercase.